# Limit of sequence of derivatives converges uniformly on compact subsets is a multiple of exponential

Tags: real-analysis

I realize the title is a mouthful. Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function with all derivatives existing. Suppose that the sequence of derivatives $f^{(n)}$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of the line to a function $g(x)$. The claim is that $g(x) = ce^x$ for some constant $c$.

I find this to be particularly elusive. Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Do all the derivatives converge to the same function $g(x)$?

Comment: I don't understand. The claim is that the sequence of functions $g_n = f^{(n)}$ converges to some multiple of the exponential function.

Comment: Understood, thanks.

Comment: Well since $f^n$ converges this means that you can find $N$ such that $|f^n - g| < \epsilon $ $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and $n> N$. So what is the solution to $f^n = f^{n+1} =\dots= g$ and this solution unique?

Comment: @Olba12 why does this imply all the derivatives are equal?

Comment: Every converging is Cauchy, so they are arbitrary close to each other. Also they are arbitrary close to g.

Comment: @Olba12 This isn't true though. The sequence $f_n = 1/n$ for every $x$ is Cauchy, but no matter how far out in the sequence you go, they are never all equal.

Comment: Well, you have not gone far enough in the sequence, when you can stop and compare they are not equal, but eventually after infinite time all points "left" will be in the same neighborhood, independt of radius. But it takes an infinte time to get there.  rather to start from beginning and going against limit. Go from limit and choose finitely many points backwards, they are all "equal".

Comment: I'm merely trying to state the intuition behind. By stating, given epsilon how many points in the sequence can you find closer to the limit than epsilon? You can find countably many. Epsilon arbitrary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h_n=f^{(n)}$. We now that $(h_n')$ converges uniformly to $g$ on all compacts. And $\lim h_n$ exists for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Consequently $h_n$ converges uniformly to a function $h$ such that $h'=g$. But we already know that $h=g$. Finally $g'=g$.

Comment: It is not clear to me where uniform convergence is needed. If $g(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f^{(n)}(x)$ then $g'(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f^{(n+1)}(x)= g(x)$